# How to remove a multi line block of text from $pattern in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the contents of a text file which is partly created by gsutil and I'm trying to put its contents in $body but I want to omit a block of text that contains special characters. The problem is that I'm not able to match this block of text in order for it to be removed. So when I print out $body it still contains all the text that I'm trying to omit.

Here's a part of my code:

```
$pattern = @"
==> NOTE: You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run
significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This
feature can be enabled by editing the
"parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto
configuration file. However, note that if you do this you and any
users that download such composite files will need to have a compiled
crcmod installed (see "gsutil help crcmod").
"@

$pattern = ([regex]::Escape($pattern))

$body = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\file.txt -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch
```

So basically I need it to display everything inside the text file except for the block of text in $pattern. I tried without -Raw and without ([regex]::Escape($pattern)) but it won't remove that entire block of text.

It has to be because of the special characters, probably the " , . () because if I make the pattern simple such as:

```
$pattern = @"
NOTE: You are uploading one or more
"@
```

then it works and this part of text is removed from $body.

It'd be nice if everything inside $pattern between the @" and "@ was treated literally. I'd like the simplest solution without functions, etc. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: I'm not sure as this part is written by the gsutil command. It's displayed exactly how you see it in $pattern. Thanks.

Comment: If I open the file in Notepad++ and enable View -> Show End of Line then I do see each line ends with CR|LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to tackle this task (without regex) would be using the `-notin` operator.  Since `Get-Content` is returning your file content as a `string[]`:

```
#requires -Version 4

$set = @('==> NOTE: You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run'
'significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This'
'feature can be enabled by editing the'
'"parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto'
'configuration file. However, note that if you do this you and any'
'users that download such composite files will need to have a compiled'
'crcmod installed (see "gsutil help crcmod").')

$filteredContent = @(Get-Content -Path $path).
    Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $set }) # trim added for misc whitespace
```

---

v2 compatible solution:

```
@(Get-Content -Path $path) |
    Where-Object { $set -notcontains $_.Trim() }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I still see the full block of text. Also, I can't be manually adding a ' after each line. The text file is as is. I can't be modifying it. I'm using PS v5.1

Comment: @yorkman I didn't modify the text file at all..  Also, it works exactly as you described in the question.

Comment: Ok, but why do I see each line start with a single quote and end with a single quote?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Copying and pasting your text with the single quotes at the beginning of every line works...this does the job for my specific case, but I'd hate to have to remove a large block of text and manually add a single quote twice on every line. Regardless, thank you. I do have a 2nd block of text to remove from the same text file...wondering how I can specify to remove two patterns.

Comment: Sorry one more thing. If I want to remove multiple blocks of text, how would I remove them all? So after the 1st pattern is removed and put in $body how do I search for another string pattern in $body and have that removed?

Comment: I managed to figure out how to remove multiple blocks of text so I've accepted your answer even though ThePing worked harder to help me. In short, to remove a 2nd block of text I just did it like this: Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $pattern1 }) | Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $pattern2 })

Comment: @yorkman You can also do `Where({ $_.Trim() -notin ($pattern1+$pattern2) })`

Comment: Even better. One last section I need to remove and am not able to is because it has a date stamp. Can I ask if there's a way I could remove it without using RegEx? At the end it has 4 lines like this that I need to remove. I can't format it as 4 lines so I'm using | to show where each line ends. Maybe I could use a wildcard for the text to match each line, something like 'End time:*' ?

********************** |
Windows PowerShell transcript end |
End time: 20190405043556 |
********************** |

Comment: @yorkman Sure, you can do `-and $_ -notlike '*end time*'`, etc. using just wildcards.  The easiest way is to just not include them in your dataset, though, instead of trying to filter them out.

Comment: How do I put that together with what I already have? You mean: Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $pattern1 + $pattern2 -and $_ -notlike $pattern3}) where $pattern3 = 'end time*' ? That gives me an error so I assume that's not where I put it.

Comment: Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $pattern1 + $pattern2 -and $_ -notlike '*End time*' }) worked but it only deleted the line that contained 'End time' however I still need to delete the 2 lines with *********************** and the Windows PowerShell transcript end lines. Am I supposed to do it on a per line basis by adding another -and $_ -notlike '***********************' ?

Answer (score 1):

With the complete text of your question stored in file `.\SO_55538262.txt`

This script with manually escaped pattern:

```
$pattern = '(?sm)^==\> NOTE: You .*?"gsutil help crcmod"\)\.'

$body = (Get-Content .\SO_55538262.txt -raw) -replace $pattern
$body
```

Returns here:

```
I'm getting the contents of a text file which is partly created by gsutil and I'm trying to put its contents in $body but I want to omit a block of text that contains special characters. The problem is that I'm not able to match this block of text in order for it to be removed. So when I print out $body it still contains all the text that I'm trying to omit.

Here's a part of my code:

$pattern = @"

"@

$pattern = ([regex]::Escape($pattern))

$body = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\file.txt -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch

So basically I need it to display everything inside the text file except for the block of text in $pattern. I tried without -Raw and without ([regex]::Escape($pattern)) but it won't remove that entire block of text.

It has to be because of the special characters, probably the " , . () because if I make the pattern simple such as:

$pattern = @" NOTE: You are uploading one or more "@

then it works and this part of text is removed from $body.

It'd be nice if everything inside $pattern between the @" and "@ was treated literally. I'd like the simplest solution without functions, etc.
```

Explanation of the RegEx from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/o6udHq/1):

```
(?sm)^==\> NOTE: You .*?"gsutil help crcmod"\)\.

(?sm) match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: gms  
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters  
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)   
^ asserts position at start of a line  
== matches the characters == literally (case sensitive)  
\> matches the character > literally (case sensitive)  
 NOTE: You matches the characters  NOTE: You literally (case sensitive)
.*?  
. matches any character 
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)  
"gsutil help crcmod" matches the characters "gsutil help crcmod" literally (case sensitive)  
\) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)  
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Nicely done! Works perfectly! Can you explain how it works so that if needed I can use this with other blocks of text as well? I'm guessing you're putting in the part with ==> NOTE as the start point and gsutil help crcmod as the end point but then there's all the weird characters like '(?sm)^*?"\)\.'

Comment: @yorkman basic regex minus the first bit.  [Those are regex engine options.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the RegEx link and putting it into practice when trying to match another set of lines. But for now, let's say I was able to figure it out, how can I match and remove multiple patterns from $body? Maybe something like: $body = (Get-Content .\SO_55538262.txt -raw) -replace $pattern $pattern2, $pattern3 ?

Comment: You can combine mutliple patterns by joining them with a vertical bar `|` in between which acts as a logical **OR** resp. [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put this into practice as I still haven't grasped all of RegEx. It'd be much easier if I could just match each line even if I have to specify the pattern with single quotes the way TheIncorrigible1 has shown below. See, I want to search for multiple blocks of patterns in a text file and remove them. I thought I could figure it out from your one pattern sample but so far I'm not able to.

Comment: I can attest that RegEx's can be quite complex and it doesn't help that treating them in PowerShell is different depending on the operator `-match`, `-replace`, `-split` - the cmdlet `Select-String` or the dot.Net variant. But it's worth learning at the sites http://regular-expressions.info and testing at http://regex101.com or http://regexstorm.net/

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I had to accept TheIncorrigible1's answer as I was able to figure out using his example how to get it to work with multiple blocks of text inside a string variable. If I could mark your answer as Assisted I would but I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Well IMO RegExes are more powerful but this comes at the expense of a steep learning curve, so nevermind: accept the answer which serves best for **YOU**.